# scroll layout with windowSoftInputMode=“adjustPan”

Tags: android, scrollview, android-input-method

I have some EditTexts(about 6-8) in one activity, so I have to use Scroll layout.

But I find that scroll layout doesn't work well with  `windowSoftInputMode=“adjustPan”`. And there's a flash at the inputmethod's area when inputmethod hides.
How would I scroll layout with `windowSoftInputMode=“adjustPan”`?

I changed `windowSoftInputMode=“adjustPan”` to `windowSoftInputMode=“adjustResize”`, but when I press the "back" button to hide inputmethod, it works very slowly and the inputmethod's background does not fit my app's theme.

Any ideas why might be wrong?

Comment: I think when you use ScrollView "adjustResize" is more convenient.

Comment: @Haresh I use adjustResize, but inputmethod works slow. I don't know why.